# resolve link errors for __imp__open and other similarly named functions using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, visual-c++-6

Link errors like this sometimes occur when compiling C++ using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__close`
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__read`
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__lseek`
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__open`

My fix, which I found after searching fruitlessly using Google for a long time, is this:

Do NOT disable language extensions. In the Project Settings dialog, in the C/C++ tab, make sure that the 'Disable language extensions' checkbox is not checked.

The functions close, read, lseek, open, etc., are not standard parts of the C library and the declarations are skipped by conditional compilation using `#if !__STDC__` in `<io.h>`. This happens if you disable language extensions.

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: Doesn't make sense either. `LNK2001` is a linker error, but `#if !__STDC__` is compile-time.

Comment: @MSalters #pragma comment(lib can get you into situations where preprocessor macros being defined or not lead to linker errors.

Comment: The point of this post is to help people who have the same problem.Yes, it does make sense. Compiler flags affect which runtime libraries are linked to the app.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that the __imp prefix refers to function stubs in the OBJ library for the DLL version of the CRT. This means your linker options are incompatible with your compiler options (linker set to static CRT or no CRT and compiler set to dynamic CRT).

In your case rather than the CRT itself it is another library, but the same idea.

Comment: That is not true. The linker and compiler options are the same.